# Match components of arithmetic expression with regex

Tags: java, regex

I created a [regular expression](http://fiddle.re/3gqvc):

```
((\(\s*)          #match start parens
|(\d+\.?\d*)      #match a number
|([+-/%^!])       #match operators
|([*])            #match the asterisk operator
|(\s*\)))+        #match the end parens
```

that is supposed to separate parentheses, numbers (integers and decimal (`3` and `6.28`)), and operators (`+-/*^%!`). I have tried a few tests

```
( (2 3 +) 6.28 +)  
(3.14 6.28 +)
( (3 4 +) (5 6 +) *)
```

and I have noticed a few things. When I run the regular expression on expressions with two start parens, it seems to ignore one of the parentheses, and testing on the site seems to yield many instances of null and repetition of characters. Is there a way to match a valid expression and assign that to it's own group? For example, if I have the expression `( (2 3 +) 6.28 +)`, the groups generated would be: [`(`, `(`, `2`, `3`, `+`, `6.28`, `+`, `)`]?

Comment: languages with matching brackets/quotes etc are not regular.

Comment: Regular expressions are not good at parsing recursive structures like the nested parentheses you have here (although some regex flavors have extensions that might be able to do achieve what you want). You need to specify what language / platform you're using, but in all honesty, I wouldn't recommend using regex for this kind of problem.

Comment: I'm doing this in java. My goal is not to do anything recursively, but simply match any parentheses, numbers (whole or decimal), and operators.

Comment: You can just drop the parens. Actually, you can just split along `[^\d+-*/.]` and you will receive a list of numbers and signs mixed together.

Comment: I dropped the parens in the [regular expression](http://fiddle.re/jqtxc) and it seems to work. One last question, though: how would I get those find strings? What I mean is, when I run it on regex planet, I get the output split into the pieces I want, but how would I store those pieces in a java array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

#### Sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test ="((6.28 + 3.14) + 7.56)";
    String re = "\\(|\\)|\\d+\\.?\\d*|[+-/%^!*]";

    List<String> components = new ArrayList<String>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

    while(m.find()) {
        components.add(m.group());
    }

    System.out.println(components);
}
```

#### Output

```
[(, (, 6.28, +, 3.14, ), +, 7.56, )]
```

Comment: yeah this is what I was looking for. Apparently using the parens screwed it up somehow.